# How do you exclude files from wiki part used in snapcraft.yaml

Tags: snap

I am using snapcraft-desktop-helpers-master to integrate my app into desktop.

I have added "after: [desktop/gtk2]" to app part, but how do i exclude files from this imported part to reduce snap file size like for example removed usr/share/doc

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple, you can override specific keywords from a remote defined part by redefining the key for the part. This would look something like this:

```
parts:
    my-part:
        plugin: autotools
        source: .
        after: [desktop/gtk2]
    desktop/gtk2:
        snap:
            - -usr/include
```

The trick here is that `desktop/gtk2` does not define a plugin entry in the parts definition hinting snapcraft to look for the full part definition from the remote parts cache.

Here I used the `snap` keyword, there are others like `stage` and `filesets`

By running

```
snapcraft help plugins
```

to read more about this some minimal examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the imported snap options by including them as an entry in your snapcraft.yaml's "parts" section. [Parts Ecosystem Blog](http://blog.sergiusens.org/posts/The-Snapcraft-Parts-Ecosystem/)